# Change height of the UICollectionView section header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

This is the method I used to adjust the height of the section header of the `UICollectionView`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize  {

        // ... calculate the height
        return headerSize 
    }
```

It only works for the first time in iOS 7. But always work for iOS 8. For example, the size is CGSize(320,50) the first time, and it will be `CGSize(320,80)` after a while.But it always be `CGSize(320,50)` in iOS 7 no matter what the size the method returned. And it's fine in iOS 8, it's changed to `CGSize(320,80)` finally.

Anybody know the reason? Thanks

Answer (score -3):

it works for me on Xcode 6 beta 4

```
func collectionView( collectionView: UICollectionView!,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGSize
{
    let size: CGSize = CGSizeMake(300, 400)
    return size
}
```

Comment: I'm talking about the height of the header.

Comment: 400 is the height of the header in this example.

Comment: this just sets the size for the cells not for the headers